# Memory Management On Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone

I am new to the iPhone SDK and I got a leak on a navigation controller.
Here is my code :

-(void)SignupClicked:(id)sender
{

```
if(appdelegate.isiPad){
    SignUpViewController *obj_SignUpViewController =[[SignUpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignUpViewControllerIpad" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj_SignUpViewController animated:YES];
    [obj_SignUpViewController release];
}
else {
    SignUpViewController *obj_SignUpViewController =[[SignUpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignUpViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj_SignUpViewController animated:YES];
    [obj_SignUpViewController release];
}
```

}

I am getting leaks on these lines:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj_SignUpViewController animated:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj_SignUpViewController animated:YES];
```

Please help me...
Thank you...

Comment: This code is fine.. Try to clean and analyze again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you push a view controller onto a navigation controller, it gets retained. Therefore, you need to release it right afterwards or you will get a leak.

```
[obj_SignUpViewController release];
```

Comment: Er, the example code does release `obj_SignUpViewController`.

Comment: Yeah, he added that after seeing the response